# Styles and scripts not working when change route (vue.js + laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, icheck

I have included some scripts in my blade file, but it didn't work, and the reason is that the scripts are loaded before the `app.js`, but I added `defer` attribute for tags and it seemed to work fine, but when I change to another route, the style and script stopped working.

```
<script src="{{asset('assets/admin/app-assets/vendors/js/forms/icheck/icheck.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
```

Is there a solution and an explanation for this problem?

Comment: Do you include this file in your other routes files?

Comment: @Syazany 
The script is included in the blade file in the footer section of all components.
For example
`@include ('admin.include.header')
@yield ('content')
@include ('admin.include.footer')`
Where the vue components (SPA) is located in the content section